# Sqlite3 trouble when I push on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I have some trouble to push my rails app to heroku.

I have the error

> Failed to install gems via Bundler.
>   remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
>   remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

So i did follow the instructions on the link, however, I still have the same error. I've tried to have a look on others similar subjects, but still not working ..

Any idea?

**UPDATE**
Here's what my gemfile looks like :

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

> While easy to use, SQLite is not intended as a production grade database. Instead Heroku provides production grade PostgreSQL databases as a service.

Don't use sqlite on heroku - assure that you don't have `sqlite3` gem in the global scope or `:production` group of your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlite3 for your unit tests and development environment is fine but on production you would want to use something like PostgreSQL.

Here is what your Gemfile could look like:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Also if you are writing unit tests you should set your sqlite3 database URL to `sqlite::memory:` for your unit tests and not your actual database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont really understand what should I do ... I'm gonna update my question.

Comment: When running bundle install you want to add the --production tag to it. `bundle install --production`. Also make sure sqlite3 is not in your Gemfile.lock.